# Convert a loop to a lambda in python 3 to return true or false with out using filter method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I wrote following code to get *True* of *False* if an element of a list is duplicate in it. I want to convert this code to a lambda version to reduce code length. Is there anyway to do it without using **filter()** method?

```
def isoscelesTriangle(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s.count(s[i]) > 1:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Do you accept a shorter code, but not `lambda` version?

Comment: Actually my main goal is to get a lambda version and I know this code can get shorter using other techniques but I'm looking for lambda version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `lambda`:

```
def isoscelesTriangle(s):
    return any(map(lambda x: s.count(x) > 1, s))
```

But, seriously you only need below one. This requires you to only compare length of list with length of it's `set`:

```
def isoscelesTriangle(s):
    return len(s) != len(set(s))
```

Comment: Tanx, you're right on using len() and len(set(s)) but I had confusion about using filter() and map() in lambda version.